# Method PUT is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response vue-laravel App

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I am new in vue. For ajax request I am using axios and for back-end I am using Laravel. Whenever I send a POST and GET request it's works fine. But while trying to send a **PUT** Request its showing Method PUT is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response vue-laravel App. I had read lots of answer in Stackoverflow and github but none of them worked for me.

Here is the client side code:

```
axios.put('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/photo/6', this.photo, { headers: getHeader() })
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data.message);
   }).catch(err => {
        this.errors = err.response.data.errors;
   });
```

Here is CROSS middleware code:

```
//allowed client 
    //now only for localhost vue cli
    $domains = ['http://localhost:8080'];

    if(isset($request->server()['HTTP_ORIGIN'])){

        $origin = $request->server()['HTTP_ORIGIN'];

        if(in_array($origin, $domains)){
            header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '.$origin);
            header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Authorization');
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
```

Comment: it's your server configuration that's doing that

Comment: Look carefully at your error, it mentions `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`, look now at your server code, you are missing a line that sends this header

Comment: I also added this line to my CROS middleware header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: ', ''POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS''); still the result is same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in backend :
app/Http/Middleware/Cors.php

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
return $next($request)
    ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, 
OPTIONS');
}
```

app/Http/Kernel.php $routedMiddleware array add

```
'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
```

Route/api.php
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'cors'], function () {

```
Route::put('/v1/employees', 'Employees@store');
```

});

Answer (score 2):

Particular GET, HEAD and POST HTTP requests do not trigger the CORS preflight OPTIONS check. They are called Simple Requests. They only send a subset of HTTP headers along. Any other additional header, like an Authorization header (think JWT authentication), will trigger a preflight OPTIONS request. The details on this can be found on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

I think the easiest way for you to work with this, is to use the laravel-cors package on the backend (see https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors).

While doing development, you can simply be very permissive by setting allowedOrigins, allowedHeaders and allowedMethods to *. Later on, during testing and subsequently production, you should tune it to be more strict. By that time you'll have a much better hang of CORS concepts, and then you can configure it fully to your needs.