# Laravel: Method PUT is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, axios

I have a Vue.js SPA being served by a Laravel backend. Both are separate projects. I am using [fruitcake](https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors) to handle CORS but I keep getting this error:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://domain.test/api/v1/attributes/3' from origin 'http://localhost:8081' has been blocked by CORS policy: Method PUT is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response. GET, POST methods work fine.

I have tried the solutions from similar problems here but none seem to work. I have even tried creating my own middleware like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50462656/method-put-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-methods-in-preflight-response). Here is my config/cors.php that I am using with fruitcake.

> ```
> 'paths' => [],
> 'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
> 'allowed_origins' => ['*'],
> 'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
> 'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
> 'exposed_headers' => [],
> 'max_age' => 0,
> 'supports_credentials' => true,
> ```

I had assumed that 'allowed_methods' => ['*'], means all requests will be allowed.
Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 2):

You have to configure at least one path, so that the middleware knows which routes to hook into:

```
'paths' => ['api/*']
```

Comment: That did not work. I still got the same error after 'allowed_methods' => ['GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT'] and running config:clear.

Answer (score 0):

I'm use this code

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $response = $next($request);
    $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT');
    $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'XMLHttpRequest, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Authorization, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers');
    
    return $response;
}
```

Comment: I just created a middleware called Cors and added that. Then I added the middleware to the beginning of protected $middleware in kernel. Didn't work.

Comment: i don't know but it works in my code  try clear cache by php artisan optimize or php artisan optimize:clear

Comment: version of laravel ?

Comment: "laravel/framework": "^8.40",